# How can i turn back the default behavior of my localhost ports?

Tags: service, next.js, port

I was using next js and i was trying to change the the default page , so i tried this

```
    module.exports = {
    async redirects() {
      return [
        {
          source: '/',
          destination: '/try/test1',
          permanent: true,
        },
      ]
    },
  }
```

But now when i back to react and start a new project the localhost:3000 always redirect to
localhost:3000/try/test1/
i tried to reverse it , but not working  :

```
module.exports = {
        async redirects() {
          return [
            {
              source: '/try/test1',
              destination: '/',
              permanent: true,
            },
          ]
        },
      }
```

and i also mess up with port 4000 too
I shouldn't use permanent : true ,

How can i get back to default?
I am using Linux Mint Xfce

Comment: Stopping the running server and re-starting it should be enough do apply any changes in `next.config.js`, including `redirects `.

Comment: That may be caching in your browser then - try clearing your browser's cache.